# Is there a way to get maxima to return expressions sorted alphabetically by the variable names?

Tags: syntax, output, cas, maxima, alphabetical-sort

I would like to get the maxima output sorted alphabetically by the variable names.
e.g. that y*x will be returned as x*y and also y+x is returned as x+y.

I know I can change the outcome of the order by using ordergreat and orderless. So I tried

```
ordergreat(x,y)$y+x;
```

which nicely prints

```
 x+y
```

but then

```
ordergreat(x,y)$y*x;
```

returns

```
 y*x
```

So I tried orderless, and it gave me the opposite result; it only seems to affect the outcome of the times. Combinations of orderless and ordergreat also did not work.

Is there a way to get maxima to return expressions sorted alphabetically by the variable names?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `powerdisp : true` has the effect you want.